# Secure Login through Email URL

Tags: security, email, authentication

I would like my users to be able to login instantly by following a URL in their email:

Such as:

Hello User, Click here to access your account:  https://mysite.com/?user=12345&login=38904753290875

The user number would be fixed, but the login would NOT be a password, just a ONE TIME access token with a 24 hour expiration.

Is this secure, or do I still need to ask them for their password when logging in?

Note, when logged in, the user won't be able to change their password without giving their password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this secure, or do I still need to ask them for their password when
>   logging in?

The security depends on your authentication design. 
Good security, even a single sign-on, doesn't depend on a single action.

Things to consider:

transport of sensitive information (for example, even if the url is https, how sure are you about their email providers)
- the impact of what these users could do in worst case scenario's
- how to detect unauthorized actions, since the 'id' has 24 hour free play?